# sharekit :: EXC_BAD_ACCESS @ shareItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova, sharekit

I try to send an image with the help of shareKit without using an actionSheet but using my own button with

```
...
// --- add the mail button ------------------------------------
UIButton *buttonMail = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonMail.frame = CGRectMake( 0,0, btnW, btnH); 
[buttonMail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonMail addTarget:self action:@selector(sendPerMailEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...

        // the sharekit image object
        item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Name of the image" ];
        item.text = @"some text...";
        [SHK setRootViewController:self.webView.window.rootViewController];
...
```

and

```
-(void)sendPerMailEvent:(id)sender {    
    [SHKMail shareItem:item];
    [self closeScreenshotView];
}
```

but when I click the button xcode is throwing me an "**EXC_BAD_ACCESS**" error at the first line of shareItem():

```
+ (id)shareItem:(SHKItem *)i
{
    [SHK pushOnFavorites:[self sharerId] forType:i.shareType]; // -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am new to objective-c and the app is made with use of phonegap.
thnx!

Comment: When you set item to a SHKItem where is the image coming from? I don't see it initialized before [SHKItem image:image title:@"Name of the image"];

Comment: the image is there and waiting: 
`UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
...
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];`
and in my .h-file I initialized the item like `@interface MyPlugIn : PGPlugin { NSString* callbackID; SHKItem* item; } @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I found out: I needed to add a `[item retain]`, thats it.

Answer (score 1):

First off the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal is telling you, you are trying to access an object after it has been deleted.

The issue here looks like you are not initializing the object & it is being released before you need it.

Try this:

```
SHKItem* item = [SHKItem alloc] init] 
[item seTitle:@"Name of the image"];
```

and see whether you still get this problem.

In future if you are get EXC_BAD_ACCESS try turning on the NSZombieEnabled environment
[link here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

Secondly. You can override the dealloc method of the class that gives you you're EXC_BAD_ACCESS and print a stacktrace to show you what is deallocating it using:

```
NSLog(@"I've been dealloced by: %@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Comment: but in my .h-file I initialized the item like `@interface MyPlugIn : PGPlugin {
    NSString* callbackID;
    SHKItem* item;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;`. was this wrong?